# How to return value from database in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

Do you have any ideas how value which was writeback from SF to database could be returned from data base again to Spotfire input field.

(No just any value, what is mechanism stay behind it?)

If I need to make changes in this record ?

We writeback to DB with IronPython scripting assigning document properties.

Piece of code....

sqlIns = "INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME (FIELD, WELL, WELLBORE, WELLTYPE) \n\
         VALUES \n\

```
   ('" + Document.Properties["IFIELD"] + "', \n\
    '" + Document.Properties["IWell"] + "', \n\
    '" + Document.Properties["IWellBore"] + "', \n\
    '" + Document.Properties["IWellType"] + "')"
```

print sqlIns

dbsettings = DatabaseDataSourceSettings( "System.Data.OracleClient","Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server)(PORT=****))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=****)));User Id=;Password=",sqlIns)

ds = DatabaseDataSource(dbsettings)
newDataTable = Document.Data.Tables.Add("temp",ds)

Document.Data.Tables.Remove(newDataTable)
The problem is that before updating into the database the record, this record needs somehow modify. I insert the data through input or drop-down field in the text area, then press the Submit button to insert it into the database. It recorded there and appeared in the table which I add on the same page in SF.

My thoughts that it should be workflow like: highlight record you want to change (it happened in a table connected to SF)
 -> once you choose the record, it appears in the input screen (input screen - text area where you enter all these values for the first time or another input screen only for data modification)
 -> make required changes
 -> re-write/update data to DB (with replacement initial record.)

Comment: Try to make your question more clear by adding a code example.

Comment: Code is not really help. it is more about Spotfire functionality. Input field based on property. according to ironpython created property insert into oracle table. 
but the question is if i want to correct record writeback from SF to database. how return this record to modify and re-write again.

Answer (score 0):

The python script just sends an sql command. That command can be changed to do an update instead of an insert.

Post an example of code that you are using for the insert and people can assist on how to change to an update statement.

You'll need to have a primary key or other identifier for the update statement.

If you "wrote back to a database" to read the data into a input Field or table you'd have to query the database (a normal query to pull data into spotfire)